# I'm not able to run the react web project and npm install also not working

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm getting following errors if npm install
[image]

i tried clean cache also like this
[image]

if i directly run the project it's shows react it shows
"'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

[image]

this is the package.json code used in my project i'm not getting what's the issue bcoz i'm new to react.let me know how to run the project.. thanks in advance..

```
{
  "name": "pay-management",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.1.5",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "autoprefixer": "7",
    "change-case": "^4.1.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "material-ui-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "postcss": "7",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-csv-importer": "^0.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^11.2.4",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.4",
    "react-papaparse": "^3.11.1",
    "react-resize-observer": "^1.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.6.2",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "globals": {
    "_": true
  },
  "homepage": "url",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcssinjs/macro": "^0.17.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1-compat"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're seeing trying to run build makes sense. You can't run your **build** script if you haven't installed the dependencies first - since you don't have the libraries necessary to compile the project yet! `npm run build` is a synonym for  "react-scripts build" according to your package.json file, so you need react (which is part of your dependency list). You have to solve the dependency conflicts first - then you can run build.

The npm dependecy conflict message tells you the steps to follow in order to solve them, read them and follow those. **AFTER** trying those official steps, if they don't help, as the last resort I would try upgrading manually autoprefixer to be v 10.0.2 ~it appears you installed it manually while developing without knowing tailwind was going to use it internally.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok thanks let me check